# show record in gridview based on fromdate and enddate entered in textbox

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have 3 textboxes-Name,FromDate and StartDate.When i enter name in 1st textbox and click button,it should display record cooresponding to that record.If i enter from date and to Date ,it should display record having Date of Birth within that range of entered value.
Name searching is working.But Search based on Date is not working..I want code in asp.net.
Pls Help...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetSearchResume]                          
@Name varchar(50)=''      
,@FromDate varchar(15)='',                                          
@ToDate varchar (15)=''                                          
AS                          
BEGIN                          
DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(8000) 
SET @SQL = 'SELECT Name,Address,Gender,Marital_Status,Email_Id,Country,State,District,Current_Salary,Total_Salary,Experience,Current_Position,                     
convert(varchar(15),DOB,101) as DOB from Resume'
if(@Name <> '')                          
BEGIN                          
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' where Name like ''%'+  @Name + '%'''                          
END   

IF(@FromDate<>'' and @ToDate<>'' )                                          
begin                                          
set @SQL=@SQL+'or DOB between '''+ CONVERT(varchar(12),@FromDate,101) +''' and ''+  CONVERT(varchar(12),@ToDate,101) +''' '                                               
End                       
print @SQL        
--select (@SQL)                          
exec (@SQL)                          
END
```

If i dont enter name and i enter from date and to date,it should display record based on that dates...Pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Stored procedure like below...
In your Stored procedure if name is empty then 'Where' is miising for Date field.

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetSearchResume]         
@Name varchar(50)='',
@FromDate varchar(15)='',
@ToDate varchar (15)=''      
AS   BEGIN 
DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(8000)  
SET @SQL = 'SELECT Name,Address,Gender,Marital_Status,Email_Id,Country,State,District,Current_Salary,Total_Salary,Experience,Current_Position, convert(varchar(15),DOB,101) as DOB from Resume' 
if(@Name <> '')    
 BEGIN            
           SET @SQL = @SQL + ' where Name like ''%'+  @Name + '%'''                           END   

IF(@FromDate<>'' and @ToDate<>'' )                                   
begin        
  if(@Name <> '')    
    BEGIN           
      set @SQL=@SQL+'or convert(varchar(15),DOB,101) between '''+ @FromDate
+''' and ''' +  @ToDate +''' ' 
    END    
  ELSE 
    BEGIN  
      set @SQL=@SQL+' Where convert(varchar(15),DOB,101) between '''+ @FromDate +''' and ''' +  @ToDate +''' '  
    END     
End                        
print @SQL        
--select (@SQL)          
exec (@SQL)                   
END
```

Comment: your code always shows first 2 records irrespective of date entered

Comment: in which format u r passing the date to Stored Procedure?

You need to pass like this 

EXEC usp_GetSearchResume '','12/20/2012','12/27/2012'

Comment: Check without entering the Date whether it is returning the all the rows are only 2 rows.  And add your code here how your calling the stored procedure...

Answer (score 0):

Please go through following method to reduce dynamic string query problems.

It will find records from past 10 days

```
declare @fromDate datetime = GETDATE()-10
declare @ToDate datetime = GETDATE()

where 1= case   when @fromDate IS NOT NULL AND @ToDate IS NULL AND CreatedOn >
@fromDate  THEN 1 
            when @fromDate IS NULL AND @ToDate IS NOT NULL AND CreatedOn <   @ToDate  THEN 1 
            when CreatedOn between @fromDate AND @ToDate THEN 1 end
```

Answer (score 0):

code on aspx page will be as follows:

```
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtToDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server">
    <SelectParameters>
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtName" DefaultValue="%" Name="Name" PropertyName="Text" />
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtFromDate " DefaultValue="%" Name="FromDate" PropertyName="Text"/>
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtToDate" DefaultValue="%" Name="txtToDate" PropertyName="Text"/>
    </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
</div>
</form>
```

and code on button click event will be as follows:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    string name = txtName.Text;
    string fromdate = txtFromDate.Text;
    string todate = txtToDate.Text;

    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Clear();
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@Name", name);
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@FromDate" , fromdate);
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@ToDate", todate);
    GridView1.Visible = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following modified store procedure and add parameter only when text box is not empty.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetSearchResume]                          
@Name varchar(50)=NULL     
,@FromDate datetime=NULL,                                          
@ToDate datetime =NULL                                          
AS                          
BEGIN                         


SELECT  Name,Address,Gender,Marital_Status,Email_Id,Country,State,
        District,Current_Salary,Total_Salary,Experience,Current_Position,                     
        convert(varchar(15),DOB,101) as DOB from Resume
where Name like  '%'+ISNULL(@Name,Name)+'%' 
or DOB between  ISNULL(@FromDate,DOB) and  ISNULL(@ToDate,DOB)

END
```

.cs page

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(path);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_GetSearchResume", con);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 


        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtName.Text))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtNames.Text; 
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFrom.Text))
        {
            DateTime str1 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFrom.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FromDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = str1;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtTo.Text))
        {
             DateTime str2 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTo.Text);           
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@ToDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = str2;
        }
```

Comment: please see the updated code. make sure you pass the date by converting it into datetime format.

Comment: Convert.ToDateTime(txtboxID.Text);

 objSqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@yourparameter", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Converteddatetimevariable

Comment: it is showing error like this-String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: hope you are passing  'mm/dd/yyyy' format, check before adding parameters if textbox is not null and you can also check for dateformat by using validator control.

Comment: name search is correct.but if i dont enter name and i enter date only,then it is not working

Comment: you dont have include namespace separately, its under String class of System namesapce.

Comment: showing error-'string' does not contain a definition for 'IsNullOrWhiteSpace'

Comment: hope datetime is the datatype for dates column.